# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS not recognize USB tethering

Tags: networking, usb, internet, samsung, tethering

I have a Galaxy J8 device (Android 10) and My PC has Ubuntu 20.04 LTS version. When I'm trying to connect phone to usb and turn on USB tethering Option. my the PC. Network settings says "Cable unplugged". I tried many (ifconfig, lsusb) ways but they not worked. lsusb direct "Samsung electronics.co device Network Ethernet,Usb debugging enabled" But no connection I can't browse. Please help me.

Comment: Please outline the steps you have taken in the many ways so we may help you and not repeat what you have already tried.

Comment: "Cable unplugged" suggests that the USB network interface was successfully brought up, but the laptop somehow didn't receive an IP address. As @David suggested, please elaborate more. Try posting the output of `ifconfig` and `lsusb`

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: Please enter the commands `ifconfig` in a terminal with the USB cable to the phone connected and tethering turned on, on your phone. Then copy the output of the command and paste directly into your question above. Repeat for `lsusb`. Finally format the pasted text as `code` using the { } icon above the edit question window.

Comment: senooedu@Bixby:~$ ifconfig
enp6s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:24:54:92:c0:53  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Comment: lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 9057  bytes 728982 (728.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9057  bytes 728982 (728.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Comment: senooedu@Bixby:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 020: ID 04e8:6863 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy series, misc. (tethering mode)
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2a7a:938f  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 09da:c10a A4Tech Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: ifconfig and lsusb output command are above 3 comments.